# Reading daemon logs for wlan0

Tags: networking, wifi, daemon, wlan

I have a `Raspberry Pi` device which runs on `Raspbain Linux`. The device performs well on `wlan0` but from the last few days, it became offline (disconnected from the network). I thought of looking into some logs and found `daemon.log` file in `/var/log/` which contains some useful information about the network connectivity wlan0. I did `cat daemon.log | grep wlan0` and it showed all the logs.

I tried to understand all the logs and got the basic idea but just wanted to know a bit more about the logs as few terms are not understandable.

```
Apr  9 04:59:33 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: carrier acquired
Apr  9 04:59:33 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: adding address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df
Apr  9 04:59:33 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: IAID eb:d3:4c:54
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: soliciting a DHCP lease
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: offered 192.168.0.57 from 192.168.0.1
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: soliciting an IPv6 router
Apr  9 04:59:34 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: probing address 192.168.0.57/24
Apr  9 04:59:35 device avahi-daemon[325]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df.
Apr  9 04:59:35 device avahi-daemon[325]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv6 for mDNS.
Apr  9 04:59:35 device avahi-daemon[325]: Registering new address record for fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df on wlan0.       *.
Apr  9 04:59:38 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: leased 192.168.0.57 for 86400 seconds
Apr  9 04:59:38 device avahi-daemon[325]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.57.
Apr  9 04:59:38 device avahi-daemon[325]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
Apr  9 04:59:39 device avahi-daemon[325]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.57 on wlan0.IPv4.
Apr  9 04:59:39 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24
Apr  9 04:59:39 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: adding default route via 192.168.0.1
Apr  9 04:59:39 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: removing route to 192.168.0.0/24
Apr  9 04:59:47 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: no IPv6 Routers available
Apr  9 05:15:49 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: carrier lost
Apr  9 05:15:49 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: deleting address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Withdrawing address record for fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df on wlan0.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv6 with address fe80::bac5:f37d:9bb4:65df.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Interface wlan0.IPv6 no longer relevant for mDNS.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device dhcpcd[332]: wlan0: deleting default route via 192.168.0.1
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.57 on wlan0.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.57.
Apr  9 05:15:49 device avahi-daemon[325]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
```

So above, it says carrier accquired and `192.168.0.57` was offered by the router(192.168.0.1). It tried to connect on that IP and leased was given for 86400 seconds (24hrs). But after this, when it says `wlan0: adding route to 192.168.0.0/24`. What does it means.?

I am not able to understand whats actully happening with it. Can anyone please explain this to me.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Very quick overview:

`dhcpd` handles [Dynamic Host Configuration Protcotol (DHCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol) responses, in other words, IP addresses that are assigned to your computer by your home router. This assignment ("lease") comes with a duration ("24 hrs").

`avahi-daemon` handles [Zeroconf/Bonjour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-configuration_networking) messages, in other words information about local devices in your homenetwork, especially for Apple devices (or other devices that use this protocol).

The `adding route` message together with the network range means that after you got an IP address via DHCP, your networking setup was made aware that all these addresses (somewhat simplified 192.168.0.0-192.168.0.255, in your example) are now reachable via `wlan0`. This is typically done by executing `ip route add ...` or a similar command. Try `ip route show` as root to see your current routes.

You can easily find more information, and introduction into networking, with a bit of googling.

None of this will help in debugging the connection problem. Have a look at the output of `dmesg` or at `/var/log/syslog*` instead.